# How to add two label-field pair as one row to QFormLayout?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwidgets

So I have QFormLayout that manages my QLabel-QLineEdit pairs just fine. 
Problem is, that I need to achive something like this:
[image]

Horizontal border/tittle isn't a problem, but "Street"-"Apartment"/"Post code"-"City" pairs are.

So my question is: **how to add two pairs of QLabel-QLineEdit as one row to QFromLayout?**

If it's not possible with QFormLayout, do you have any suggestion about achivining the same with other layout (QGridLayout, I guess)?

Keep in mind, that labels can have different size proportions after translated to other languages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about simply clicking this together in QtDesigner? Should be rather straightforward. And yes, you could use a QGridLayout in code and simply put Appartment and City into column 1 while the single lines have columnSpan set to -1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for all the response!

I've ended up adding QLabel as label and QHBoxLayout with QLineEdit, QLabel and QLineEdit as field to QFormLayout.
Something like:

```
QLabel firstLabel, secondLabel;
QLineEdit fisrtEdit, secondEdit;

QHBoxLayout hBoxLayout;
hBoxLayout.addWidget(firstEdit);
hBoxLayout.addWidget(secondLabel);
hBoxLayout.addWidget(secondEdit);

QWidget container;
container.setLayout(hBoxLayout);

myFormLayout.addRow(firstLabel, container);
```

do the trick!

Also, if you're planing to add more than one row like this, I'll need to set all `secondLabel`s to one fixed width. I did this by iterating over all `secondLabel`s twice: first time for finding maximux width and second for setting this width to all of them.

A bit hacky, but I couldn't find a better way so far. Solution with QGridLayout would be even more complicated, on my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a QWidget with get a Vertical layout with the QLabel and the QLineEdit then add the label in the QFormLayout. I don't get the time to show you an example but think about to create an ui with a QLabel-QLineEdit in a QVBoxLayout.
By creating an ui you can add any widget in with the same form easily.

So you mainWindow. you main layout -> create your widget -> add vertical layout -> add your QLabel and QLineEdit to yout widget layout -> add your widget to your main layout.

I think you should show a QtCreator-QtDesigner tutorial. It will take you some time but you will get really faster after.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately, I really can't understand what do you mean. Could you describe your solution in greater details, please?

Comment: It's better to use nested layout management (native Qt solution). It means that you create a separate `QFormLayout` for you right column and add it using `addRow(QLayout * layout)` to your parent layout.

Comment: dazewell it's way faster to use QDesigner to do the ui and it's what you do with my solution. @Roman use QtCreator. Create a new class -> Qt -> Qt form -> Widget -> in you widget.ui create a QLabel and QLineEdit, right click -> vertical layout. return in your main class where you want to add you QLabel-QLineEdit create an objet of you custom widget class then make an layout->addWidget(yourWidget);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a label without the QLineEdit to appear, you can define a QlineEdit and hide it:
(the code is in python, just to show the principle)

```
self._dummy = QLineEdit(self)
self._dummy.hide()
layout = QFormLayout(self)
layout.addRow("text without an edit field", self._dummy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I just created for my solution, this is a pseudo code version that might help someone.

```
    def create_gb_f(self):
        gb = QGroupBox("F") 

        ly_horiz = QHBoxLayout()

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow( label, edit)
        ly_horiz.addLayout(layout)

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow( label, edit)
        ly_horiz.addLayout(layout)

        ly_horiz.addWidget( button)
        gb.setLayout(ly_horiz)
        return gb
```